# How can I download file from SFTP using pysftp?

Tags: python, pysftp

I have a SFTP server that contains a set of folders. I would like to download a file from one of these folders.

Can someone help me with the python code?

Where should I start?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the example [in pysftp's documentation](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/release_0.2.9/)?

```
import pysftp

with pysftp.Connection('hostname', username='me', password='secret') as sftp:
    with sftp.cd('public'):             # temporarily chdir to public
        sftp.put('/my/local/filename')  # upload file to public/ on remote
        sftp.get('remote_file')         # get a remote file
```

Comment: srv = pysftp.Connection(host="", username="",password="", cnopts=cnopts)

Comment: Is that something you tried? Did you get any errors? If so, please update your question to reflect what you've tried already.

Answer (score 1):

An addition from Michael Powers.

If your server is one account and your personal account is another one.
 If your server account has root permission, then follow Michael's method.
 If no, you may use io buffer to download this file

```
    import io
    server_sftp = pysftp.Connection(host=test_host, username=server_account,
                              password=server_pwd, cnopts=cn_opts)
    your_user_sftp = pysftp.Connection(host=host_name, username = user_name,
                                password = user_pwd, cnopts=cn_opts)

    try:
        file_like=io.BytesIO()
        server_account.getfo(server_file_location,file_like)
        your_user_sftp.putfo(file_like, target_file_location)
    finally:
        flie_like.close()

    server_sftp.close()
    your_user_sftp.close()
```